# Adding and removing elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a generator for a mod menu in Call of Duty. I want people to be able to add a menu or delete one. I'm trying to id the menus sequentially so that I can use the text field values correctly. I made it so that if they delete a menu it changes the ids of all the other menus to one lower and same for the button id, but I don't know how to change the onlick event to remove the right element.

Better yet, if there's a better way to do this, I would love to know it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    y = 1
    function test2()
    {
        document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML += "<div id=\"child" + y + "\"><input type=\"text\" value=\"menu name\" \><input id=\"button" + y + "\" type=\"button\" value=\"remove?\" onclick=\"test3(" + y + ")\" /></div>";
        y++;
        alert(y);
    }
    function test3(x)
    {
        document.getElementById("test2").removeChild(document.getElementById("child" + x));

        for(var t = x+1;t < y;t++)
        {
            alert("t is " + t + ". And y is " + y);
            document.getElementById("button" + t).setAttribute("onclick" , "test3(t-1)");
            document.getElementById("button" + t).id = "button" + (t-1);
            document.getElementById("child" + t).id = "child" + (t-1);
        }
        y--;
    }

</script>
<input value="testing" type="button" onclick="test2()" />
<div id="test2" class="cfgcode"></div>
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), this is a widely-used Javascript library that makes tasks such as these, and many others, a lot easier.

Comment: Why don't you try this library: http://jquery.com/ ? It's called JQuery, and you will have a less painful adventure with javascript :-).

Comment: Yes, jQuery is certainly the way to go. Besides that: Put `var` before all vars when using them he first time (`var y = 1;`) and use proper function names, i.e. not `test` unless that function is actually testing something (and even in that case, `testSomething` would be more appropriate)

Comment: 2003 called, they want their syntax back ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about re-indexing all of the elements after you add or remove one, that seems a waste. It would be better to simply write a more generic function, rather than one with the element id hard coded into it.

For example, your first function could be written as so:

```
function genericFunction(el)
{
    var html = ''; // create any new html here
    el.innerHTML = html;
}
```

You can then add onclick handlers such as:

```
myDiv.onclick = function() { genericFunction(this) };
```

I would also agree with all the commenters above, use jQuery, it makes any code which interacts with the DOM much much simpler.

Comment: The question asked was: "I don't know how to change the onlick event to remove the right element". I offered a better way to handle the onclick event so that it would always know the right element (by passing in `this`). How is that not an answer?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll delete my comment